# Catch exits after only one exception

Tags: c#, append, try-catch, stringbuilder

In my try/catch shown below, the application loops through the words that were entered into the textbox by the user. (I have already verified that this part works.) As it loops through the words it passes each word the function below.

```
private string runQuery(string data)
    {
        // Step 1 - Declare the query and parameters
        SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=keywordDB.sdf");
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT abbrev, description FROM abbreviations WHERE abbrev LIKE @abbrev", connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@abbrev", data);
        SqlCeDataReader reader;

        try
        {
            // Step 2 - Opens the connection
            connection.Open();

            // Step 3- Execute query and assign the data to abbrevQueryResult and results
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            abbrevQueryResult = reader[0].ToString();
            results = reader[1].ToString();

            // Step 4 compare abbrevQueryResult to data entered by user in textbox
            if (abbrevQueryResult.ToLower().Equals(data.ToLowerInvariant()))
            {
                returnResults.Append(" " + results + ",");
            }
        }

        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            badData = new StringBuilder();
            badData.Append(" " + data);
        }

        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        return returnResults.ToString();
    }
```

I've noticed that if I enter in 6 words, 3 of which should work fine, and 3 which should be caught by the catch statement that the catch statement will only catch the very last one. Any idea why it only catches one of the words? I'd love for it to catch all of them and add them all to the StringBuilder badData.

Comment: You say you are looping, but I don't see any loop construct.

Comment: @Ikke: The loop is outside this function. This function gets called for every word inside the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't show where `badData` is declared.  However, every time your catch block gets called, you're resetting `badData` to a new StringBuilder - meaning its old instance (and any values held within it) are discarded.  If you remove this line within your catch block:

```
badData = new StringBuilder();
```

you'll probably be closer to where you want to be.

When you end up with a null pointer exception after doing this, you'll need to ensure that `badData` is instantiated to `= new StringBuilder();` (as you had it) wherever you already have it declared - I.E., as an instance variable outside of the method.

Answer (score 5):

You really should not be using the try/catch and exception mechanism to determine the validity of your data in an ordinary situation like this.  That's why it is called an 'exception' because it is intended to handle exceptional cases that might crash your program.  If you expect that a certain percentage of your input will be invalid, then do an ordinary logical test for it.

```
 if (valid(word) {function(word);} else {addToErrorList(word);}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `badData = new StringBuilder();` everytime in the catch block. So, it does get caught 3 times, but you only see the last bad word in your `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 1):

If you want `badData` to contain all of the errors, then you cannot initialize the variable in the catch clause, because then you are resetting the variable for each exception that is caught. If you initialize it elsewhere, this can work.

Initializing it at the top of your class:

```
public class MyClass {
     private StringBuilder badData = new StringBuilder();

     // Other code
}
```

Initializing it in your constructor:

```
public class MyClass {
     private StringBuilder badData;

     public MyClass() {
          badData = new StringBuilder();
     }
}
```

By doing like this, the variable will exist as long as the object exists, and then you just have to remove the initialization in the catch clause so that the variable will not be reset to a new `StringBuilder` object each time an exception is caught (and thereby all of the errors will be appended and not just the last one).

Answer (score 1):

That SQL access code is very fragile and my guess is that's the cause, but the point is, your exception handling is not adequate because you only catch InvalidOperationException. Add another catch at the end for type Exception to find the cause of the early bomb-out. (And as ziesemer said, stop reinitializing the sb.)